# Use a Library in the processor's generated classes

Tags: java, android, annotations, dependencies, gson

I'm developing a library to generate classes using annotations and processors. The generated classes should use `Gson` library from google.

My question is : **Where should I add the Gson dependency ?** I'm currently adding it into the processor build.gradle but when the classes are generated, Gson is not found and Android Studio is suggesting to add it to the app module.

**build.gradle** of the **processor** :

```
implementation project(':lib-annotation')
implementation 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0-rc3'
```

**build.gradle** of the **app** :

```
implementation project(':lib-annotation')
annotationProcessor project(':lib-processor')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**P.S.** The project is meant to be a library. I expect the users to only include my library in their gradle file, not the "sub dependency".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally fixed the problem!

I had to add the `Gson` dependency into the **processor** build.gradle using `implementation` **or** `compile` :

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

And add the dependency again into the **annotation** build.gradle using `compile` :

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
```

---

I think it wasn't working because the `Gson` dependency was in the **processor** build.gradle which is included using `annotationProcessor 'lib-processor'` (Somehow the "transitivity" wasn't applying). Therefore I put the `Gson` dependency in the **annotation** build.gradle since I include it using `implementation 'lib-annotation'` and it worked.

Hope it will help

Comment: or you can add gson to `lib-annotation` using `api` or `compile` and then use compile project `compile project(':lib-annotation')` that make - your lip is transitive on whole this libraries, and you added it only once.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using **implementation** prevent you from using **transitive dependency**.

The main project can't use or invoke the dependencies you added to your library.

As reminded to [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) the **implementation** configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

So you have to use `api` OR `compile` instead of `implementation` or add a condition to your transitive library e.g :-

```
implementation ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'){
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ibrahim ! I tried the three options you suggested above, and none of them worked... Gson still can't be found in the generated class (unless I add the dependencie to the main project of course...)

Comment: Do you think I'm getting the `Javapoet` error because I'm using `implementation` instead of `compile`or `api` ?

Comment: @OmarAflak no i think it happened because you didn't added `kapt 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.6.1'`, while the main issue because you didn't use `api` or `compile`. at least it should work with `compile` if you make all right.

Comment: I think `kapt` is the kotlin version of `apt`. Aren't we supposed to use `annotationProcessor` now ?

Comment: @OmarAflak then you probably using an old version of dagger, on other hand, what your `pom.xml` look like ?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact implementation hides the dependency and therefore keeping it out of the app's path (so if you need to expose Gson, avoid using implementation), the problem is due to being compiling/implementing the library module instead of using a regular aar/jar/apklib package. Try this:

-Add the Android Maven Gradle plugin to the library project and configurate it.

-Using the plugin, compile and install the library into your local maven repository.
-instead of using compile/api/implementation for adding the library to the app, include mavenLocal() into your build.gradle, and then add the library as a regular dependency. All the necessary dependencies should be there.

here's an example of the plugin, in case you need it: https://github.com/fcopardo/EnhancedMapView

Answer (score 0):

follow this link, I have imported without any problems.
http://blog.madadipouya.com/2015/09/21/how-to-add-gson-library-to-android-studio-project/

Comment: you can also download the jar file and import it in that way. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1

Comment: it's not about including the library in a simple project... I could just add to my gradle file `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'`. I'm trying to include the library in the processor's generated classes...